# Java high cpu usage Debian

Tags: java, debian

When I run any Java program on my Debian server (e.g. tomcat, jvirtualvm) the cpu usage spikes to 100% and then always stays between 80% and 120%. As jvirtualvm also leads to this problem, I can't really use it to debug. Any ideas how I could find out more?
This happens when I use sun-java or open-jdk. I installed both from the repositories.

Comment: I would use a CPU profiler to see what it is doing e.g. VisualVM should be enough.

Comment: @PeterLawrey As I wrote in the edit, virtualvm also seems to suffer from the same problem. Is there anything not Java-based I could use to look at what Java is doing?

Comment: I use a commercial profiler, YourKit, which is uses a native agent (i..e no Java overhead)

Answer (score 1):

I did have the similar issue before trying to run tomcat on ubuntu, I was using apt-get to install tomcat packages as it's easy, but it seems very complicated to use.

So I tried installing tomcat from http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.35/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.35.tar.gz

Just download the tarball, and extract it to /opt like this

```
wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.35/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.35.tar.gz
tar xfzv apache-tomcat-6.0.35.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-tomcat-6.0.35 /opt/tomcat
```

Now if you have JDK installed already, just start your tomcat with,

```
sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

and then access your tomcat,

```
http://localhost:8080
```

You might need to remove your existing tomcat packages first.

Comment: This seemed to help, I can now access it under localhost:8080, something that was not possible before. But it still uses loads of CPU and shutdown.sh hung up, so I had to kill it again. Something is not working right, I'guess I'll have to try a CPU profiler again.